# How can you allocate a raw mutable pointer in stable Rust?

Tags: rust, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

I was trying to build a naive implementation of a custom `String`-like struct with small string optimization. Now that unions are allowed in stable Rust, I came up with the following code:

```
struct Large {
    capacity: usize,
    buffer: *mut u8,
}

struct Small([u8; 16]);

union Container {
    large: Large,
    small: Small,
}

struct MyString {
    len: usize,
    container: Container,
}
```

I can't seem to find a way how to allocate that `*mut u8`. Is it possible to do in stable Rust? It looks like using `alloc::heap` would work, but it is only available in nightly.

Comment: FWIW, `String` itself cannot use the SSO because of certain methods it exposes. You won't be able to replicate the complete API, but hopefully that doesn't prevent your use cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Rust 1.28, [`std::alloc::alloc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/alloc/fn.alloc.html) is stable.

Here is an example which shows in general how it can be used.

```
use std::{
    alloc::{self, Layout},
    cmp, mem, ptr, slice, str,
};

// This really should **not** be copied
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct Large {
    capacity: usize,
    buffer: *mut u8,
}

// This really should **not** be copied
#[derive(Copy, Clone, Default)]
struct Small([u8; 16]);

union Container {
    large: Large,
    small: Small,
}

struct MyString {
    len: usize,
    container: Container,
}

impl MyString {
    fn new() -> Self {
        MyString {
            len: 0,
            container: Container {
                small: Small::default(),
            },
        }
    }

    fn as_buf(&self) -> &[u8] {
        unsafe {
            if self.len <= 16 {
                &self.container.small.0[..self.len]
            } else {
                slice::from_raw_parts(self.container.large.buffer, self.len)
            }
        }
    }

    pub fn as_str(&self) -> &str {
        unsafe { str::from_utf8_unchecked(self.as_buf()) }
    }

    // Not actually UTF-8 safe!
    fn push(&mut self, c: u8) {
        unsafe {
            use cmp::Ordering::*;

            match self.len.cmp(&16) {
                Less => {
                    self.container.small.0[self.len] = c;
                }
                Equal => {
                    let capacity = 17;
                    let layout = Layout::from_size_align(capacity, mem::align_of::<u8>())
                        .expect("Bad layout");

                    let buffer = alloc::alloc(layout);

                    {
                        let buf = self.as_buf();
                        ptr::copy_nonoverlapping(buf.as_ptr(), buffer, buf.len());
                    }

                    self.container.large = Large { capacity, buffer };

                    *self.container.large.buffer.offset(self.len as isize) = c;
                }
                Greater => {
                    let Large {
                        mut capacity,
                        buffer,
                    } = self.container.large;
                    capacity += 1;

                    let layout = Layout::from_size_align(capacity, mem::align_of::<u8>())
                        .expect("Bad layout");

                    let buffer = alloc::realloc(buffer, layout, capacity);

                    self.container.large = Large { capacity, buffer };

                    *self.container.large.buffer.offset(self.len as isize) = c;
                }
            }

            self.len += 1;
        }
    }
}

impl Drop for MyString {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe {
            if self.len > 16 {
                let Large { capacity, buffer } = self.container.large;
                let layout =
                    Layout::from_size_align(capacity, mem::align_of::<u8>()).expect("Bad layout");
                alloc::dealloc(buffer, layout);
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut s = MyString::new();

    for _ in 0..32 {
        s.push(b'a');
        println!("{}", s.as_str());
    }
}
```

I believe this code to be correct with respect to allocations, but not for anything else. Like all `unsafe` code, verify it yourself. It's also completely inefficient as it reallocates for every additional character.

---

If you'd like to allocate a collection of `u8` instead of a single `u8`, you can create a `Vec` and then convert it into the constituent pieces, such as by calling [`as_mut_ptr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.as_mut_ptr):

```
use std::mem;

fn main() {
    let mut foo = vec![0; 1024]; // or Vec::<u8>::with_capacity(1024);

    let ptr = foo.as_mut_ptr();
    let cap = foo.capacity();
    let len = foo.len();
    mem::forget(foo); // Avoid calling the destructor!

    let foo_again = unsafe { Vec::from_raw_parts(ptr, len, cap) }; // Rebuild it to drop it
    // Do *NOT* use `ptr` / `cap` / `len` anymore
}
```

**Re** allocating is a bit of a pain though; you'd have to convert back to a `Vec` and do the whole dance forwards and backwards

<del>That being said, your `Large` struct seems to be missing a `length`, which would be distinct from capacity. You could just use a `Vec` instead of writing it out.</del> I see now it's up a bit in the hierarchy.

I wonder if having a full `String` wouldn't be a lot easier, even if it were a bit less efficient in that the length is double-counted...

```
union Container {
    large: String,
    small: Small,
}
```

---

See also:

- [What is the right way to allocate data to pass to an FFI call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39550856/155423)
- [How do I use the Rust memory allocator for a C library that can be provided an allocator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39250335/155423)

Comment: The length field is in `MyString` which also contains `Large` or `Small`.

Comment: @interjay ah, indeed.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you! Somehow I did not realise I could use Vec for the allocation and deallocation.

Answer (score 3):

What about [`Box::into_raw()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.into_raw)?

```
struct TypeMatches(*mut u8);
TypeMatches(Box::into_raw(Box::new(0u8)));
```

But it's difficult to tell from your code snippet if this is what you really need.  You probably want a real allocator, and you could use [`libc::malloc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/regex/libc/fn.malloc.html) with an `as` cast, as in [this example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.pointer.html#3-get-it-from-c).

Comment: That allocates a single `u8`. OP wants a buffer of more than one.

Comment: @interjay that's true, but the question as asked is just how to allocate *a pointer*, and this is a valid answer to that. I'd expect that people coming from search engines will find this question and answer useful.

Answer (score 2):

There's a [memalloc crate](https://github.com/reem/rust-memalloc) which provides a stable allocation API. It's implemented by allocating memory with `Vec::with_capacity`, then extracting the pointer:

```
let vec = Vec::with_capacity(cap);
let ptr = buf.as_mut_ptr();
mem::forget(vec);
```

To free the memory, use `Vec::from_raw_parts`.